# Was I deported from Finland, and how should I answer the related question on a DS160 form?

Tags: usa, covid-19, eu, finland, deportation

I'm an EU citizen. I entered  Finland by foot during covid-related border controls. It was a city where one half is Finnish and the other half is Swedish.  Border control took me to the station for a search, then sent me back to Sweden with some paper. They said it was just a warning and next time I will be fined. They didn't take my fingerprints or a picture of me.

After two months I entered Finland again with an invitation letter from my boyfriend and they let me in the country with a brief questioning. Was I deported the first time or was I just refused entry to the country? Is this info in my passport? Could I be denied an f1 because of this?

Comment: the F1 part of your question probably belongs on expats once you know whether this was a deportation or not

Comment: Ok, thank you :)

Comment: It's going to depend on the exact wording of the question you are trying to answer.

Comment: The question is: have I ever been removed or deported from a country?

Comment: To me it sounds more like i was refused the entry

Comment: what does the papers you were given say ?

Comment: I dont know. It was in finnish which I dont speak. I dont even have it anymore.

Comment: @Karca123 Since the border guards threatened with a fine next time, it sounds to me as if you were caught after having entered Finland illegally and not just merely been refused entry. Without the paperwork, which you don't have anymore, it is difficult to say. You can contact Finnish authorities though and request a copy of your record.

Comment: Did the border police in Haparanda register your ID?

Comment: They did register it because when i return  3 months after the incident  to finland the border guard saw it in my record and took me for questioning but they let me in Finland anyways. So I dont know.

Comment: Things may be complex, but they must gave you a paper or something like that (with legal procedure you can follow). If they didn't give it, you got just a "friendly" reminder. Also COVID makes things difficult: as EU you can enter to FI (so not a deportation): the restriction were police measures (and often also within the same country). I tend to think most the latter: you got "just" a police warning on entering in a zone you are supposed not to be.

Comment: As an EU citizen, it would be relatively difficult for you to violate Finnish *immigration* regulations. On the other hand, there are/were plenty of COVID-related *quarantine* regulations. Could that explain your situation?

Comment: @o.m. Finland reinstated border controls until relatively recently, and so it was in fact quite possible for an EU citizen to violate immigration regulations at the internal borders, for example by crossing at other than a border crossing.  As such, they were probably indeed refused entry, but I'm not sure about the grounds for a fine.

Comment: @Lll, that's what I meant by quarantine. The OP wasn't prohibited from being in Finland in general, he was prohibited from crossing into Finland at that time and place.

Answer (score 10):

Your best bet is to send a Subject Access Request to the Finnish border authority, asking for a copy of your record. You are entitled to this information under the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR).
You should provide

1. Your name on the passport, and date of birth
2. Passport number, and your nationality
3. Its start and end dates
4. The dates and locations of the two incidents

The contact addresses are here https://raja.fi/en/contact-information

They should send a copy of the letter you were given during the first incident, and if there are any issues with you re-entering again.
Legally, you can use any EU language in your request, but Finnish, English, or Swedish will be your best bet.